# Android: Arraylist to ListView

Tags: android, arraylist

I got this class, I recieve all the data as Array in this code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {      
    return "ChampionList [" + champions + "]";
}
```

How can I set the code that I recieve to a ListView?

This is the class code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    

public class ChampionList {
    public ArrayList<Champion> champions;
    public ArrayList<Champion> getChampions() {
        return champions;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return "ChampionList [" + champions + "]";
    }

    public void setChampions(ArrayList<Champion> champions) {
        this.champions = champions;
    }       
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

You will find an example there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an Adapter. Read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews